# White space around <label> tag in bootstrap form-inline and form-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-chrome-devtools

When looking at bootstrap [*Inline form*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) docs, you can see a space between the label and it's input (marked in yellow below):

[image]

---

When inspecting it in chrome dev tools, I can't see any margin/padding/etc.

[image]

---

Even more, created this simple [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-marging-padding) from copy pasting bootstrap's example code, **but there is no white space at all!**

(**NOTE:** In my StackBlitz DEMO, stretch the display on the right a bit to get the inline form styling apply.)

[image]

---

My question is actually two question:

1. Where is this white space from bootstrap's docs page is coming from?
2. How do I see the styling that apply this white space when inspecting this in chrome dev tools?

**Thanks a lot in advance.**

Comment: If you inspect HTML of the parent you'll see there's a space between the tags.

Answer (score 2):

A line-break within the soruce code is rendered as a white space for inline-elements by most browsers. As mentioned before, you can set the font-size to 0 to prevent this.

Inspecting the source-code of the bootstrap example page actually reveals not only a line break but even a white-space for the specific elements. That Angular-App you postet probably strips all line-breaks and white-spaces before rendering the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain in greater details the line break and white-space inspection, what does it tells us? Another thing, can you explain in greater details what do you mean by *That Angular-App you posted probably strips all line-breaks and white-spaces before rendering the source code*, what do you mean by *strips*? how does it does that? and how do I see this in inspection?

Answer (score 1):

inline and inline block element have white space / gaps around them.

One way people get round this is to set the font-size of the parent element to `font-size: 0;` and then specify the desired font-size to the children.

I hope that explains.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me understand what is going on here with gaps around the blocks. Can you explain why there is no gaps in my attached DEMO sample? I can see there is font size to the body, so I don't understand why this is not getting the gaps too.

Answer (score 0):

Inline blocks are treated as text elements, so surrounding spaces and newlines get counted as white space.

```
<div class="inline-block">A</div>
<div class="inline-block">B</div>
```

The newline between div A and div B gets output as space.
Following are html based methods of suppressing white space

```
<div class="inline-block">A</div><!-- comment suppresses white space
--><div class="inline-block">B</div>

<div class="inline-block">A</div><div class="inline-block">B</div>  <!--everything on same line without spaces-->
```